# Getting an error "No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I'm trying to rebuild my app with the latest version of Android Studio (Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2) and am now getting this error:

No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:266)

The thing is, my app doesn't overtly contain any Kotlin modules, so I don't understand the error.

Here is my app level Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.uomini.perisecure"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 100
    versionName "1.100"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    starter {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId 'com.uomini.perisecure.starter'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 17
        versionName '1.17'
    }
    main {
        dimension 'version'
        applicationId "com.uomini.perisecure"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.100"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
sourceSets {
    starter {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/starter/java'
        }
    }
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
  }
}

dependencies {

// Import the Firebase BoM

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.0')
// Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
// When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-installations'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:18.7.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
constraints {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
}

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Also, I've got version 33 of the SDK installed:
[image]